# Postgres unable connect to server: connection failed: FATAL: password Authentication docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, pgadmin-4

After download the image of postgres and pgadmin and run via docker-compose correctly both of them, after login in pgadmin, in creation database I'm not able to authentication adding the correct parameter setted in the docker-compose.yaml.
[image of error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvaH9.png)

Below the docker compose file:

```
version: '3.3'

networks: 
  ntpgsql:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.21.0.0/24

services:
  pgsql:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: postgresql
    volumes: 
      - psdb-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks: 
      ntpgsql:
        ipv4_address: 172.21.0.2
    ports:
      - target: 5432
        published: 5433 
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxx
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: pgadmin4
    
    networks:
      ntpgsql:
        ipv4_address: 172.21.0.3
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE=True
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=xxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxx


volumes:
  psdb-volume:
```

Error container log:

```
postgresql | 2023-07-09 14:45:23.981 UTC [35] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
postgresql | 2023-07-09 14:45:23.981 UTC [35] DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
```

Why I'm not able to login and why there is this authentication error with a default user?
Thanks

Comment: What is the full error reported in the container log for the database container?

Comment: If the client gets a password authentication error but the server doesn't log its own version of that same error, that suggests the client connected to a different server than you think it did.

Comment: Error: postgresql | 2023-07-09 14:02:44.490 UTC [39] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Comment: The server version of the error should include at least one DETAIL line describing the nature of the failure.

Comment: Sorry the details is : Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256". Adding in docker compose the instruction POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS=--auth-host=scram-sha-256 the result never change

Comment: Your docker file works as expected for me.  I can use the same password (10 x's) to log into first pgadmin, and then the database.  It sure looks like you are just using the wrong password to log into the database.

Comment: The password is the same and used correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can related to the used volume:

```
volumes: 
  - psdb-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Try to use a different path, maybe there are problem with valume and user authorization.

Comment: Thanks the problem was related to the wrong permission volume